# Coins : Invalid Method Declaration, return type required

Tags: java

I just started Computer Science last week, and we got a worksheet called Coins, in which I had to find out how many quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies there are in a set of coins. I am having a lot of trouble, and getting that error. Here's my code

```
package Coins;


public class Coins
{
    private int change;

    // two contructors
    Change()    //default constructor
    {
        change = 94;
    }

    Change( int c )
    {
        change = c;
    }

    // accessor method - change
    public int getChange()
    {
            return Change;
    }



    // mutator method - change
    public void setChange( int anotherChange)
    {
        change = anotherChange;
    }

    public void askUserForChange()
    {
        Scanner keyIn;
        keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the amount of change: ");
        String input = keyIn.nextLine();

        int nChange = Integer.parseInt (input);

        setChange(nChange);
        // change = nChange

        printChangex();
    }

    // action method - take accessor figure out coins -> output
    // calculating the coins needed for the change
    public void printChangeRange(int start, int end)
    {
        for(int c = start; c <= end; c++
        {
            setChange(c);
            printChangex();
        }

    }
    public void printChangex()
    {

    int c = change;
    int quarter = c / 25;
    System.out.println("quarter = " + quarter);
    int a = c%25;
    int dime = a / 10;
    System.out.println("dime = " + dime);
    int b = a%10;
    int nickel = b / 5;
    System.out.println("nickel = " + nickel);
    int c = b%5;
    int penny = c / 1;
    System.out.println("penny = " + penny);

    }


    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    public Coins()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        x = 0;
    }

    public int sampleMethod(int y)
    {
        // put your code here
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: When reporting errors you should include the information you have, like where it is in the code. Even though it's trivial in this case, it's important to provide details.

Comment: There are lots of errors here which suggests that you're coding style is wrong. If you can't use an IDE, then it is your responsibility to compile early and often, probably after each line of code, and to not add any new code until current compiler errors have been fixed.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please let us know. Also if any of the answers have helped you, you should click the green check mark to accept an answer. Good luck with your Java!

Answer (score 4):

You have a class named `Coins` and are trying to give it a constructor named `Change`. The class and constructor must have the same name. Just pick one.

To elaborate on the error in your title, I assume that "Invalid Method Declaration, return type required" refers to the line with `Change()    //default constructor`. Since this is in a class called `Coins` it is not a constructor as the comment claims. The Java compiler thinks that it is a method. All methods must have a return type, so the compiler complains.

The actual constructors are at the bottom of your code. It is standard practice to put constructors first, so I suggest that you put these poperly-named constructors at the beginning of your `Coins` class. You probably just need to remove the `Change()` constructors completely.

Also as a tip for asking questions here, it is extremel critical that you post the complete error message you are getting. My answer is based on some educated guesses and certainly don't solve all the problems in your code. Feel free to come back with more questions as you keep trying to fix your program.

Comment: Which is weird, because there's a `Coins` constructor at the bottom.

Comment: @DaveNewton Which is apparently outside of any class...something is missing.

Comment: @Code-Guru:  It's not outside of the class at all.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
// two contructors
Change()    //default constructor
{
    change = 94;
}

Change( int c )
{
    change = c;
}
```

is unusual.  You even have a constructor for the class `Coins` at the bottom of the file, so you would want to use that.  Keep in mind that all Java classes have a constructor that are **named the same as the class itself** - even if it's the default constructor.

<sup>It's even *more* unusual that it has the magical value of 94 on instantiation...but in all seriousness, pick a class name and stick with it.</sup>

This

```
// accessor method - change
    public int getChange()
    {
            return Change;
    }
```

...is also odd.  You may want to return the member variable `change` instead, so change that to a lower case C.